# Breeze - SPA - Upload files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, breeze, single-page-application

I am looking to upload files via my SPA, but obviously would like for files to only be associated with the current item that is being created.  How would I create this association?

My first thought was to set a cookie, but if the client doesn't accept cookies, this would obviously fail.

What would my other options be?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "current item being created".

Assuming you're doing a breeze create call to your existing backend, and you hope to upload to that same backend, and somehow cross reference the created item to the uploaded file, then perhaps you need to simply upload, then create.

In my single page web apps, I like to upload to an intermediate store, get a unique id back as part of the upload, then pass that unique id to my create operation.  The create logic in my server simply reads from the intermediate store using the unique id and secured access.  This allows me to maintain a reusable intermediate store, and not bog down my logic backend with a slow file upload.

Comment: I think the approach I am going to take is:

1) Create Item
2) Then from the edit screen that I am redirected to (after creation) provide the upload here.